# pop modal pages to root

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

How I can navigate to root page?
I navigate to modal page

```
_navigationService.NavigateAsync("QuestionDetail", navParams, useModalNavigation: true);
```

And then I use

```
_navigationService.NavigateAsync("QuestionDetail", navParams);
```

for navigating to other pages.

How I can directly back to my root page?

Comment: Usually you can call navigation.PopToRoot(), don't know if it works on Modal page, but you can still cal navigation.PopModal() before pop to root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no PopToRoot for modal navigation.  To achieve what you want use an absolute URI.

_navigationService.NavigateAsync(new Uri("myapp:///MainPage", UriKind.Absolute));

or

_navigationService.NavigateAsync(new Uri("http://myapp.com/MainPage", UriKind.Absolute));

Comment: But I lose my navigation parametrs on my root page :(

Comment: Yes, because you are resetting your entire navigation stack to a new page.  Otherwise, you have to call GoBackAsync, the number of times required to reach your root.  You could save off your parameters or pass new parameters to your page on navigation.

Comment: Time to new feature? I think it's be very usfull

Comment: This isn't even available in Xamarin.Forms.  I think you should reevaluate the navigation flow of your application.